# I need to add Criteria on Workflow if current user profile ="System Administrator" then update the field

Tags: workflow, workflowrule

Requirement: I used `$profile.Name= "System Administartor"`.I am confused whether it will check current user profile who is updating/creating record.
Please help

Comment: It will check the current user profile

Comment: @LironC you can put that as answer.

Comment: @TusharSharma Done, just thought it is obvious for most of us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will check the current user profile